# Manjaro Linux cannot open source file "gtkmm.h"

Tags: c++, gtkmm, manjaro

I have been trying to set up my coding environment for GUI development in c++ recently, with little success.  I use Manjaro Linux with Visual Studio Code, but for some reason, I always seem to get include errors when including files that I **know** are there.

Most recently, I tried to set up gtkmm-4.0 by installing the package and the documentation.  I double checked in `/usr/include/` to ensure the packages were all present, but I still am getting include errors:
`cannot open source file "gtkmm.h"` and
`gtkmm.h:No such file or directory`

At this point, all the code I have is:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
exec = game.out
sources = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
objects = $(sources:.cpp=.o)
flags = -g $(shell pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --cflags)
libs = $(shell pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --libs)


$(exec): $(objects)
    g++ $(objects) $(flags) -o $(exec) $(libs)

%.o: %.cpp include/%.h
    g++ -c $(flags) $< -o $@

install:
    make
    cp ./game.out /usr/local/bin/game

clean:
    -rm *.out 
    -rm *.o
    -rm src/*.o
```

I have scoured the internet for answers, but everything I found was either for a different os/environment or just didn't

@Galik and @John helped me solve this!

What I had to do was use `g++ src/main.cpp -o main $(pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --cflags --libs)` to compile my code, then run the executable.

Thank you both for your help and guidance!!

Comment: You probably need to learn about [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) and read the documentation of your compiler, usually [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Be aware that Visual Studio Code is not a compiler (it runs one, usually `g++`)

Comment: You need to add the header search path to the compile command and the library search path to the link command. How are you compiling this?

Comment: I have been (attempting to anyway) compiling my program with a Makefile, but I also tried just using `g++ main.cpp -o main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `pkg-config`and add this to the compiler flags in your `Makefile`:

```
flags = -g $(shell pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags)
libs = $(shell pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --libs)

# ...

$(exec): $(objects)
    g++ $(objects) $(flags) -o $(exec) $(libs)
```

The tool `pkg-config` has a database of the correct paths for supporting libraries.

Depending on your version if gtkmm, you may need to substitute `gtkmm-3.0`, if you have version `3.0`.

Comment: I made these changed to my Makefile, but I am still getting the include errors.  I also attempted running the program by just typing `g++ src/main.cpp -o main 'pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --cflags --libs'`, but still to no avail.
I also checked my /usr/include/ directory and found that there was no `gtkmm.h` file there.  I could copy it from the `gtkmm-4.0` directory into `/usr/include/` but I am loath to do so as I have seen other people do the same thing only to end up in an eternal loop of having to move more .h files into `/usr/include/`

Comment: @Christian what does `pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --cflags` display if you just run it in the console?

Comment: @john https://pastebin.com/KT6PJMC2

Comment: @Christian Well as you can see it's expecting the header files to be in `/usr/include/gtkmm-4.0` and `/usr/lib/gtkmm-4.0/include` etc. Is that where you have the header files?

Comment: @Christian Please also post the latest content of your makefile. There's probably just some simple error in that.

Comment: @Christian That command should not use single quote `'`, it should use a back-tick `. As in `g++ src/main.cpp -o main `pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --cflags --libs``

Comment: @Christian I generally use `g++ src/main.cpp -o main $(pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --cflags --libs)` to be safer

Comment: @john I updated my post with the most recent Makefile.  Also, I checked `/usr/include/gtkmm-4.0` and `/usr/lib/gtkmm-4.0/include` and some other files and found `gtkmm.h` there...

@Galik I ran the command `g++ src/main.cpp -o main $(pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --cflags --libs)` and the code compiled!  There is still the red underline in VSC, but I can live with that.